# How best to utilise incremental compilation in sbt

Tags: sbt, zinc

I want to gain an understanding of how incrementational compilation can be done on sbt. Having done a bit of research I have found that Zinc is one way of achieving this. [sample zinc implementation](https://github.com/pauldraper/zinc-example).

Would love to hear any pointers that people would have to best measure how effective zinc can be

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of both Zinc and Bloop.

Zinc is the standard (and only) way of doing incremental compilation in Scala. You can expect it to do the right thing and compile your code efficiently.

If you want to integrate with it, I recommend using [Bloop](https://github.com/scalacenter/bloop) which improves on zinc to compile your code faster than a custom zinc integration.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback , so am I correct to say that Zinc is already built into sbt ? and if so what advantage does Bloop give me over running the sbt  console , if Zinc is already incorporated ?

Comment: Zinc is built into more or less every build tool in the ecosystem. Bloop gives you faster compilation than the one you get from sbt. But I misunderstood your goal, if you are just a user and this is your first time in Scala, I recommend you use sbt first.